# Role of rdl file in SSRS Mobile reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Can we use RDL files in SSRS to design mobile reports?  My understanding is that RDL files are used for creating printable reports and not for mobile reports.  Mobile reports can be only designed using Mobile Report Publisher tool.  Could you please validate if my understanding is correct or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The Mobile reports are a completely different file type and you use separate designers to make them.